# unable to add new products in magento2

Tags: javascript, typeerror, magento2, adminhtml

Unable to add new product in magento2.After click on add new product loader keeps running.(sometimes it works fine)i found that issue "Uncaught TypeError: component.getPreview is not a function" in import-handler.js file line no 44.Is there any solution for fix this error?
magento version 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late, but please try to remove meta_description from your attribute set and try again.

Let me know if you succeeded!

Comment: Thanks Paul.Its working

Answer (score 1):

This may happen when you've attribute group code 'description' set, even though you change label but if `attribute_group_code` = 'description' then it may create issue with PageBuilder element "description" in 2.4.3

So just change the attribute code to something else, for example: "desc"

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute_group` SET `attribute_group_code` = 'desc' WHERE `attribute_group_code` = 'description';
```

And clear cache, that's all!